# python and iteration specifically "for line in first_names"

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

If I 'pop' an item off an array in python, I seem to shoot myself in the foot by messing up the array's total length? See the following example:
Also am I just being an idiot or is this normal behaviour? And is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

```
first_names = []
last_names = []
approved_names = []
blacklisted_names = []
loopcounter = 0

with open("first_names.txt") as file:
    first_names = file.readlines()
    #first_names = [line.rstrip() for line in first_names]

for line in first_names:
    line = line.strip("\r\n")
    line = line.strip("\n")
    line = line.strip(" ")
    if line == "":
        first_names.pop(loopcounter)
        #first_names.pop(first_names.index("")) # Does not work as expected
        #loopcounter -= 1 # Does not work as expected either......
    loopcounter += 1
        
loopcounter = 0


def save_names():
    with open("first_names2.txt",'wt',encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.writelines(first_names)
```

and the resulting files:

```
first_names.txt 
{

Abbey
Abbie
Abbott
Abby


Abe
Abie
Abstinence
Acton
}
```

And the output file

```
{
Abbey
Abbie
Abbott


Abe
Abie
Abstinence
Acton
}
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting for code
Code blocks can be highlighted using highlight.js. In many cases, the syntax highlighting language will be inferred from the question's tags.

To manually specify the language of a fenced code block, add the language to the line with the opening fence:

``` lang-js
setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: I also tried asking for the index in "for line, index in first_names:" but it threw an exception......

Comment: are there a bunch of different whitespace characters in the text file that you can't handle with just strip()?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Not apart from the junk I put into it but it will accept user input and I was wanting to make sure that I cleansed the file, I'm not going to bother doing anything about you holding down alt ant hitting random numbers on the numeric keypad tho.......... So makes me wonder why i'm doing it at all...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.pop()` removes an item from a list and returns the value (see e.g. [this ref](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_pop.asp)). For the very basic task of cleaning and writing the list of names, an easy edit would be:

```py
with open("first_names.txt") as file:
    first_names = file.readlines()

cleaned_lines = []
for line in first_names:
    clean_l = line.strip("\r\n").strip("\n").strip(" ")
    if clean_l != "":
        cleaned_lines.append(clean_l)

with open("first_names2.txt",'wt',encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.writelines(cleaned_lines)
```

If you don't want to create a cleaned copy of the list first_names, you could iteratively append single lines to the file as well.

```py
with open("first_names.txt") as file:
    first_names = file.readlines()

with open("first_names2.txt",'wt',encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in first_names:
        clean_l = line.strip("\r\n").strip("\n").strip(" ")
        if clean_l != "":
            file.writelines([clean_l, ])
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it most closely follows my original program flow. I wish I could upvote or mark more than one reply as an answer.... Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm going to roll with this I do wish I could post code properly as a comment on stackoverflow.com:
    def cleanselist(input_list):
        cleaned_lines = []
        for line in input_list:
            clean_l = line.strip("\r\n").strip("\n").strip(" ")
            if clean_l != "":
                cleaned_lines.append(clean_l)
        return cleaned_lines

Comment: Also need to do this before calling save: 
def cleanselistbyaddinglineterminators(input_list):
    cleaned_lines = []
    for line in input_list:
        line = line +"\n"
        cleaned_lines.append(line)
    return cleaned_lines

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not a good idea to mutate a list on which you're iterating, as you stated in your question. If you pop an element from the list you don't necessarily mess up the array's length, but you may encounter unexpected behavior when dealing with which index to pop. In this case you may skip some elements of the array.

A quick solution would be to make a copy of the list and use the built-in `enumerate()` method as follows:

```py
copy = first_names.copy()
for i, line in enumerate(copy):
    line = line.strip("\r\n")
    line = line.strip("\n")
    line = line.strip(" ")
    if line == "":
        first_names.remove(i)
```

More on `enumerate()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, was wondering why it was behaving this way and was unaware of the enumerate function.........

Comment: Will this also go out of sync if I remove an element (from the original array) then later on remove another element from the original array?

Comment: You should make a copy of the list you are about to operate on every time you wish to add and/or remove elements.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I have to re run the iteration each time I remove or add something, useful to know! I wish I could upvote or mark more than one reply as an answer.... Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The usual practice would be to filter or create a new list, rather than change the list you are iterating. It's not uncommon to create a new list with the changes you want, and then just assign it back to the original variable name. Here is a list comprehension. Note the if statement that filters out the undesirable blank lines.

```
first_names = [name.strip() for name in first_names if name.strip()]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension

And you can do the same with iterators using map to apply a function to each item in the list, and filter to remove the blank lines.

```
first_names_iterator = filter(lambda x: bool(x), map(lambda x: x.strip(), first_names))
first_names = list(first_names_iterator)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

The last line demonstrates that you could have just passed the iterator to list's constructor to get a list, but iterators are better. You can iterate through them without having to have the whole list at once. If you wanted a list, you should use list comprehension.

The lambda notation is just a fast way to write a function. I could have defined a function with a good name, but that's often overkill for things like map, filter, or a sort key.

Full code:

```
test_cases = [
    'Abbey',
    '  Abbie  ',
    '',
    'Acton',
]

print(test_cases)
first_names = list(test_cases)
first_names = [name.strip() for name in first_names if name.strip()]
print(first_names)

first_names = list(test_cases)
for name in filter(lambda x: bool(x),
                   map(lambda x: x.strip(),
                       first_names)):
    print(name)
```

Comment: I probably should have nested a generator rather than compute name.strip() twice in the list comprehension, but I wanted to move on to the iterator.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm reading the documentation you posted right now, I wish I could upvote or mark more than one reply as an answer.... Thanks for your time!